# Including related fields in Linq group by query

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm trying to create a query that groups by a field in the first table, sums a first table field, and includes a single field from a second. I keep getting an error when attempting to refer to a field from the joined table.

**Table1: Users**

```
Id
DisplayName
```

**Table2: TimeEntries**

```
WeekEnding
UserId
Hours
```

**Query:**

```
from u in Users
join t in TimeEntries on u.Id equals t.UserId
group t by new {t.WeekEnding, t.UserId } into g
select new {WE = g.Key.WeekEnding, User = g.Key.UserId, 
HoursTotal = g.Sum(s => s.Hours), DisplayName = g.First(n => n.DisplayName)}
```

I've tried many things but "DisplayName" is not a valid field.
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple options.

```
from t in TimeEntries
group t by new {t.WeekEnding, t.UserId } into g
let firstT = t.First()
select new
{
  WE = g.Key.WeekEnding,
  User = g.Key.UserId
  HoursTotal = g.Sum(x => x.Hours)
  DisplayName = firstT.User.DisplayName
}


from t in TimeEntries
group t by new {t.WeekEnding, t.UserId } into g
let user = (from u in Users where u.UserId == g.Key.UserId select u).Single()
select new
{
  WE = g.Key.WeekEnding,
  User = g.Key.UserId
  HoursTotal = g.Sum(x => x.Hours)
  DisplayName = user.DisplayName
}
```

Comment: With a little clean-up I got it!!!

The first query didn't have a join on the Users table (am I missing something?)

After cleaning up the second, I got the error: "The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."

Changing Single to Single or default got it! Thanks!!!

Comment: First query uses navigational property - TimeEntry.User (which you may or may not have) instead of joining.

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable.First(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) returns the first element in a sequence that satisfies a specified condition.

But i assume that `n.DisplayName` is a string not a `bool.`

Try the [other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) instead which simply returns the first element in a sequence:

```
DisplayName = g.First().DisplayName
```